Upload large file via Azure App Gateway and Azure APIM to Azure Storage
We need to upload large files (1 GB and above) from an Angular web application to Azure Storage. We hosted a file upload API on Azure API Management, which invokes the Azure Storage REST API (PUT Blob) to upload the file to target Azure storage location. Ideally for large file upload, we should be using chunking, i.e. multipart/form-data as the content type of the request. However, multipart/form-data is not supported in APIM policies (as per my research). Hence we are sending file as binary (i.e. content type as application/octet-stream). This works fine when we invoke the APIM endpoint for file upload (tested successfully for up to 2 GB file). However, when the web application invokes the same APIM endpoint with 1 GB file via Azure Application Gateway with WAF V2 (with CRS 3.2), the request is getting blocked as the max request size limit for WAF V2 (without file) is 2 MB only (refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#application-gateway-limits). Correct me if I am wrong, but I think WAF only considers incoming requests with content type as "multipart/form-data" as having file attachment, and in this case since we are using a different content type (application/octet-stream), the 2 MB size limitation gets applied and WAF blocks the request. Is there a way to make the flow Web App --> App Gateway with WAF --> APIM --> Azure Storage work for large files? If not, if there is any solution or workaround to this issue, given that all file upload requests must go through WAF?
Note that we also tried to send the file as "multipart/form-data" to APIM via WAF and then forwarding the request to a backend Azure Function app which then uploads the file to Azure storage. However, the backend Function App being HTTP-triggered, it could not handle more than 100 MB file size (an inherent limitation of HTTP-triggered Azure Function and Logic App).
Any suggestions will be really appreciated.

You should be able to use multipart/form-data to upload, in which case your gateway should detect it as an upload and allow it. APIM does allow you to use multipart/form-data as per the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63143532/how-to-send-post-form-data-with-file-and-data-using-azure-api-management
